# What is the Oozie alternative component in Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, oozie

I want to deploy the Hadoop based project in the Google Cloud Platform (GCP). At present, my project is being used multiple Big data stack like HDFS, Hive, Impala, Phoenix, HBase, Spark, Oozie etc. I can deploy Hadoop based cluster in GCP using DataProc; in which I use some of same components HDFS, Hive, Spark in GCP. I can use Bigtable in place of HBase. What is best way to schedule the Spark,Hive batches jobs in GCP.

What are alternative technologies similar to Phoenix and Impala?

Comment: Have you considered to use GCP [Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/workflow-scheduler) for batch spark jobs? Alternative solution for Apache Impala in GCP has been already discussed in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56384954).  Does this make sense in your research?

Comment: Thank you Nick for your comment. I would like to use DataProc workflow for spark batch jobs because we use dataproc it will not much impact present project otherwise it is going to impact entire project for necessary changes to support GCP components.

Comment: Does my comment answer you initial questions or you still need to clarify something more?

Comment: You gave me little clarification. Any other possible technique than dataproc

Comment: What do you mean writing `Any other possible technique than dataproc`?